# Can I create a style for a template and pass this in as a parameter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
             x:Class="Japanese.Templates.FooterTemplate" 
             x:Name="this" BackgroundColor="#efeff4"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="1" Orientation="Vertical" 
                 Spacing="0" Margin="0"
                 IsVisible="{Binding FooterType, Converter={StaticResource Type0BoolConverter}, Source={x:Reference this}  }" >
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FF0000" Margin="0" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#00FF00" Margin="0" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#0000FF" Margin="0" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I would like to have the background colors for the three BoxViews decided with a style that I pass in as a parameter.

Can someone tell me if this is possible and if so give some suggestions as to how I could do this.

Comment: see if this can help you out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/

Comment: Do you need to apply style on template through xaml? Not getting term pass as a parameter.